# php authentication portal, which can allow to access other servers after authentication

Tags: php, authentication, yii, proxy

I am trying to develop Authentication Portal in php using yii framework. The application will run on DMZ's Server. Our Organization's users will use Authentication Portal, from Internet, for accessing different other servers(which are also on DMZ with public IPs). Using authentication portal, user (from Internet) should get authenticated . After getting authenticated, user can access different remote servers. If user logout from Authentication portal then he/she will not be able to access remote servers. How can I make this scenario possible? Should I use transparent proxy concept? Or is there any other way I can resolve above issue? If I use transparent proxy concept can any one guide me how should I proceed.

For understanding the scenario kindly access the below given link.
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=615517178517994&set=pb.100001791512679.-2207520000.1391079267.&type=3&theater

Thanks in advance

Comment: are u trying to create Central Authentication Service read some of the options here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service. Probably openID will suite u ? or https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS

Comment: How are your servers authenticating the user? I dont understand your question very well. You could use a web page that echoes true or false if user is logged in, and use it. Or if the user has permission for somehing. Thats what I use for 2 web systems that arent written in Yii, but as a fast workaround I used some CURL calls inside the PHPs of those systems, with a helper that acts as intermediate between the App and the Yii App. Also a Javascript for checking session status every X seconds